# Converting a Website Into a Single Page App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to convert my website into a single page app. This function does the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("body").delegate("a", "click", function(){
        var href = $(this).attr("href");        
            $.get(href,function(data){
            var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
            newDoc.write(data);
            newDoc.close();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Assuming I have no redirects other than `<a>` tags, it should work fine, right? It feels so wrong and yet so right...

Comment: Umm... Are you asking us to verify if the code is correct?

Comment: @Pimgd No, I know it will work, but is it poor practice? Are there better ways?

Comment: @Pimgd The code is correct, it is just a terrible terrible practice. In my mind this question is review-able.

Comment: @konijn The main problem is that, every time a script element is placed into the page, the JavaScript will be added, right? If I could get around that, by perhaps not replacing script elements, would it still be terrible practice? If so, why?

Comment: @konijn The question got re-opened. Feel free to tell us how terrible this practice is in an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work, but consider why you might be doing SPA's:

- No more full screen flickering, better user experience
- Keep your state on the browser side instead of pingponging it between server & browser
- Less network traffic *if* you only request for data & do the rendering with templates in JS

With your approach,

- You are rebuilding the whole DOM from scratch everytime, so there will still be flickering.
- With script tags being replaced while JS is still running, I dont even want to think about what mess your state will be in ;)
- You are still fetching data + layout from the server, so not gaining anything from a network perspective.

Furthermore, you run the risk of memory leaks, which happen like this:

- Add any listener to your DOM
- Forget to unbind that listener when the user clicks a link
- New content is loaded, old DOM is gone, but that old listener is still out there